# Unity 3D how to aim a weapon to a raycast hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a weapon which shoots projectiles and i try to rotate the weapon towards a raycast hit. I attached two scripts too my weapon one for shooting and one for aiming the shooting script works fine.
Here my weapon script which inistiate my projectiles:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random; //   |source: https://community.gamedev.tv/t/solved-random-is-an-ambiguous-reference/7440/9

public class weapon_shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    //deklariere projektil |source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;
    private float projectileSize = 0;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float projectileSpeed = 50;
    public float projectileSizeRandomMin = 10;
    public float projectileSizeRandomMax = 35;

    void Update()
    {
        // Ctrl was pressed, launch a projectile
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            //random sized bullets
            projectileSize = Random.Range(projectileSizeRandomMin, projectileSizeRandomMax);
            projectilePrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(projectileSize, projectileSize, projectileSize);

            // Instantiate the projectile at the position and rotation of this transform
            Rigidbody clone;
            clone = Instantiate(rb, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            // Give the cloned object an initial velocity along the current
            // object's Z axis
            clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * projectileSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

So then i tried to cast a ray from the middle of the screen to the mouse position and then rotate my weapon towards the point where the ray collides with my world. But when i run it it shoots in all directions :=o (no errors) need some help to figure this out :)
 here is my weapon aiming script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weapon_aiming : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    private bool ray_hit_something = false;

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            ray_hit_something = true;
        } else
        {
            ray_hit_something = false;
        }

        if (ray_hit_something == true) { 
            transform.LookAt(Camera.main.ViewportToScreenPoint(hit.point));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Camera.main.ViewportToScreenPoint`? `LookAt` expects a position in world space, `hit.point` is already a position in world space,  and `ViewportToScreenPoint` has nothing to do with world space.  Have you tried simply `transform.LookAt(hit.point);`?  Also, you can just do `ray_hit_something = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);` and `if (ray_hit_something) { ... }`

Comment: you are totally right i simply changed to transform.LookAt(hit.point); and it works thx you are an angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `LookAt(hit.point)` as `LookAt` expects a position in world space and `hit.point` is already in world space:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weapon_aiming : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    private bool ray_hit_something = false;

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        ray_hit_something = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);

        if (ray_hit_something) { 
            transform.LookAt(hit.point);
        }
    }
}
```